# How to solve algebra equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today, I saw this equation on an assessment in class. Before I handed it in, I was sure to copy it down so I could ask  for some help here.

Alright, I had a lot of work down, and I always messed up on one step near the end (which I don't remember, nor can I find out as I don't have the sheet with me). So if anyone can guide me through this problem, that would be great.

$4[x-(3-2x)]+5 = 3(x+11)$

Comment: So start writing. Show your steps, and we can point out where the trouble is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4(x-3+2x)+5 = 3x+33

12x-7 = 3x+33

9x = 40

x = 40/9

Comment: Looks like you just gave a man a fish... :(

Comment: The King takes no criticism!

Comment: I actually laughed out loud.

Comment: How did -2x become +2x in your first step?

Comment: Distribute the negative! - and a - is a +, - and a + is a -.

Comment: @KingSquirrel OHH. It seems like that's where I messed up originally.

Comment: The King helps all.